# Hidden nested navigation is shown before hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a list as a navigation and CSS to design a horizontal nav for the main pages/ vertical nav for the subpages of "Diet".
I apply JavaScript to hide/ show the subpage links in the navigation. It works, but when the page is loaded the 3 links are shown - after I hovered over the item "Diet" they are hidden. If I hover again, then it is shown again and works as it should.

Basically, **how can I make sure that the three links are hidden from the beginning?**

Thank you in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nav li:has(ul)").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find("ul").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.navUnordList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navListElmnt {
  float: left;
  position: right;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.navListElmntVert {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul class="navUnordList">
    <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page2.html">Example</a></li>
    <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page3.html">Diet</a>
      <ul class="navUnordList">
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-1.html">Food and Drink </li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-2.html">Balanced Diet</li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-3.html">Nutrition</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code. It makes it much easier for others to read, and therefore help you with. I've edited the question for you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `display: none` to the submenu:

```
.navListElmnt > .navUnordList {
  display:none;
}
```

If I can express a personal note, these class names are bad, difficult to remember and to write.

```js
$(document).ready(


 function()
{

 $("nav li:has(ul)").hover(
  function()
  {

  $(this).find("ul").slideDown();
  }
  ,
  function()
  {
  $(this).find("ul").hide();
  });
}
);
```

```css
.navUnordList{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.navListElmnt{
  float:left;
  position:right;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;

}
.navListElmntVert{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-top:0.1em;
}
.navListElmnt > .navUnordList {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
      <ul class="navUnordList">

        <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page2.html">Example</a></li>
        <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page3.html">Diet</a>
            <ul class="navUnordList">
                <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-1.html">Food and Drink </li>
                <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-2.html">Balanced Diet</li>
                <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-3.html">Nutrition</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the options to start with you can set them as `display: none` in CSS.

Also note that the JS is redundant, as you can have the same logic in CSS, which is preferred as it's hardware accelerated. Try this:

```css
.navUnordList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navUnordList li ul li {
  display: none;
}

.navListElmnt {
  float: left;
  position: right;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.navListElmnt:hover > ul > li {
  display: block;
}

.navListElmntVert {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul class="navUnordList">
    <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page2.html">Example</a></li>
    <li class="navListElmnt">
      <a href="page3.html">Diet</a>
      <ul class="navUnordList">
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-1.html">Food and Drink</a></li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-2.html">Balanced Diet</a></li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-3.html">Nutrition</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have a CSS only solution for this. Keep height 0px by default and make it auto on hover like this:

```css
.navUnordList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navListElmnt {
  float: left;
  position: right;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.navListElmntVert {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}

.navListElmnt>.navUnordList {
  height: 0px;
}

.navListElmnt:hover>.navUnordList {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navUnordList">
    <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page2.html">Example</a></li>
    <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page3.html">Diet</a>
      <ul class="navUnordList">
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-1.html">Food and Drink</a> </li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-2.html">Balanced Diet</a></li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-3.html">Nutrition</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Note: This does take away the slide down animation cos of `height:auto`

But you can have animated version too, if you are ready to measure how much height each submenu takes like this:

```css
.navUnordList {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navListElmnt {
  float: left;
  position: right;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 75%;
}

.navListElmntVert {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  margin-top: 0.1em;
}

.navListElmnt>.navUnordList {
  height: 0px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.navListElmnt:hover>.navUnordList {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="navUnordList">
    <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page2.html">Example</a></li>
    <li class="navListElmnt"><a href="page3.html">Diet</a>
      <ul class="navUnordList">
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-1.html">Food and Drink</a> </li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-2.html">Balanced Diet</a></li>
        <li class="navListElmntVert"><a href="page3-3.html">Nutrition</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```